# getting bitmap out of stream in background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, runnable

I have ListView showing images which are downloading from server. Steps I need to execute are:

1. Call the api to get the stream.
2. Get bytes[] out of that stream.
3. Save those bytes in a File object (inside sd card).
4. Get the bitmap from that file path/location.
5. Show the bitmap in the ImageView.

The first 4 steps need to be executed in a background thread to keep the main thread unoccupied so that user can scroll through the list smoothly while the images are being downloaded in the background. 5th step need to be executed on the UI thread.

I am having trouble in executing these steps in background.

This is how I am trying to execute the above 4 steps in background after getting a successful response from the image download api.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // Get bytes from Response
                        byte[] bytes = getBytesFromStream(response.getBody().in());
                        // Save bytes in phone sd card
                        saveBytesToFile(bytes, photoPath);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        // Get bitmap from path
                        Bitmap webBitmap = getBitmap(photoPath);
                        // Show bitmap
                        showBitmap(webBitmap);
                    }
                }
            });

            thread.start();


private void showBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bitmap, photoToLoad);
    Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
    a.runOnUiThread(bd);
}
```

getBytesFromStream() method extracts the bytes out of stream and returns them. saveBytesToFile() method saves those bytes in the File object (sd card). getBitmap() method gets the bitmap from a particular path. showBitmap() method shows the bitmap on the ImageView.

Now my questions are:

1. Am I doing everything right?
2. What is the best way to execute something in background thread in Android?
3. I think my above code is still blocking main thread and because of which I am unable to scroll through list smoothly. How can I correctly execute these steps?

Please help me out.

Comment: You can try to use `Picasso` library with just simple steps to load the image.

Comment: Is there any reason at all you are not simply using `Picasso`? Makes no sense to reinvent the wheel when there is no need for it.

Comment: what is the actual problem ?

Comment: @bjiang I dont want to use any third party code/library. I have written my own image loading class.

Comment: @bjiang I don't use url to display the image. I have bytes of the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) instead. In your listview's adapter do the following:

```
@Override 
public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      //
      // Other codes
      //

      Picasso.with(context).load(string_url).into(imageview);
    }
```

Comment: I dont have any url for the image. All I do is I call the api and this api gives my the bytes of the bitmap. Hence I cannot use Picasso. Is there any other way? Moreover, I dont want to use any third party code. I have written my own image loading class.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your 5 steps is theoretically right.
2. Basically, the easyist way is  [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), using a`Thread` is all right, but when you need to do background work frequently you may need to try some threading strategy like [Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) to reuse threads.
3. As for fetching an loading image  efficiently, it's not that simple as your 5 steps, you should consider much more things such as caching the images on disk after first downloaded, caching some recent loaded bitmaps in memory and manage them. And as with scrolling. try not to load images when user is scrolling the list and always load the 'right'( avoid load images that are already scroll over and invisible) ImageView is also very important.
4. At last,  [smoothe](http://lucasr.org/2013/01/06/introducing-smoothie/) and [universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) are  good libraries about image asynchrous loading. You can refer to them and make your own  policy.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am also doing the file cache and memory cache part. I didn't mentioned them here because they are running perfectly. I am having issue only when downloading part comes into play.

How can I avoid loading images while scrolling?  And you also mentioned, "always load the right". How can I implement this part?

But my main question is not answered. What is keeping my main thread busy? Why is my list not scrolling smoothly?

Comment: How do you know your main thread is busy? As you post, you create every thread for a single image loading, maybe is the frequent thread creating,destroying and  thread-switch reduce your main thread's efficiency. You may be still download images when scrolling but when the image downloads and decodes finished, you should just load the image that are now visible which is easily implemented by using ListView.getLastVisiblePosition() and getFirstVisiblePosition()

Comment: You might be right. May be thread creating, destroying and switching is reducing my main thread's efficiency. Will using Executor instead of thread increase my main thread's efficiency? Since I am setting the bitmaps in ImageView inside image loader class, how will I access the listview's first and last visible position inside image loader? Should I pass listview's instance to the image loader? Additionally, how can I implement pause and resume functionality inside image loader?

Comment: Use Executor will help. you don't need to implement pause and resume, but you need to separate the image downloading decoding phase from the image presenting phase. when you get a new bitmap instance, notify to your Adapter binded to the Listview, let it judge to load the image or not.